# VBScript to refresh all excel files in a specific folder

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have some VBscript that should go out to a specific folder, open all .xlsm files within that folder, refresh all, save and close the files. This script is kicked off by windows task scheduler each morning at 4 a.m.

Currently, this script opens the first .xlsm file listed, refreshes, but does not save, then closes. no other files in the folder are opened.

This is the code i currently have:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("[file path to folder i want files updated]").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsm" Then
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    wb.RefreshAll
    WScript.Sleep 5*60*1000
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
  End If
Next

xl.Quit
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: How can you be sure about the files not being saved? The code looks ok to me. Have you tried to debug and see what is going on?

Comment: The refresh is bringing in a new line of data into a table each day. I know the files is not saving because, the data is not updated when i open the file, and the date modified is not changed. I am newer to VBscript, i have not ran a debugger. @PankajJaju

Answer (score 0):

Just change the setting of your excel to dont run in the backgrond when refreshing. This will solve your problem.